# Laravel App Loging in doesn't work on local whereas it works online

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

We have a laravel app which run online on our server (bluehost shared). This app has been pushed from bitbucket to our bluehost server where currently the app is running properly.

I have pulled from bitbucket our app and set it up on my local wamp. I have updated composer as I was getting an error warning when navigating to public just after installing the archive on my wamp.

Now when I navigate to the public folder the app display. Our home route is landing on a login / register page via this route : auth/signin I have copied the data for user from our online phpmyadmin to my local phpmyadmin (so I have user and password in our local database too). When I try to login using user and password (using same user login and same password than on the online app) I get a "Error ! Please check the form below for errors."

I have to mention that it seems our auth system seems to use Sentry as our application was initially developped with Laravel 4. This packaged seems to be called in the composer.json as require: "cartalyst/sentry": "dev-feature/laravel-5"

According to you, where the problem may come from ?

Comment: The app secret is used when hashing the passwords, so this would need to be the same across both apps too. Did you copy the app secret from the online version to your local version?

Comment: Indeed. it was. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, does that mean you're all fixed?

Comment: @fubar yes, how to close the question?

Comment: I don’t know. Perhaps just leave it for others to read the comments, should they have a similar issue.

Comment: @user92481 you or someone else could just post you solution to your question as an "answer" and then you could mark it as correct/accepted. :)